# Flow - Not able to Navigate to next screen from lightning component

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I have a custom lightning component which accepts user input and then makes a decision based on that.

However,  I am not able to move forward to the next step after that.

Can anyone help.

This is my code--

```
getVerificationCode: function(cmp, event, helper) {
      cmp.set("v.verificationCode", cmp.find('verificationCode').get('v.value'));
       console.log("Inside getVerificationCode"+cmp.get("v.verificationCode"));
     var navigate = component.get("v.navigateFlow");
      navigate("NEXT");
       navigate.fire();

   }
```

Component:

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens">
    <aura:attribute name="scriptText" type="String" required="true" default=""/>
   <aura:attribute name="verificationCode" type="String" />
   <aura:attribute name="resendCode" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="action" type="String" />

   <div class="slds-p-top_medium slds-p-bottom_medium">
       <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
           <lightning:layoutItem size="12">
                <lightning:input type="String" aura:id="verificationCode" label="Enter Verifcation Code" class="slds-p-top_small"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
           <lightning:layoutItem size="12">
               <lightning:button label="Ok" aura:id="btnOk" variant="Primary" onclick="{!c.getVerificationCode}"/>
           </lightning:layoutItem>
           <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
                <lightning:button label="Return to Login" aura:id="btnCancel" variant="neutral" onclick="{!c.navigateToLogin}"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
           <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
               <lightning:button label="Resend Code" aura:id="btnResend" variant="Primary" onclick="{!c.resendCode}"/>
           </lightning:layoutItem>
           <aura:if isTrue="{!v.resendCode}">
                <lightning:layoutItem size="12">
                    Verification Code Resent!
                 </lightning:layoutItem>
            </aura:if>
        </lightning:layout>
   </div>
</aura:component>
```

Design Resource:-

```
<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="verificationCode" label="Verification Code" />
    <design:attribute name="resendCode" label="Resend Code" />
     <design:attribute name="action" label="Navigation Action" description="" />
</design:component>
```

Debug Logs

46.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,FINEST;CALLOUT,FINEST;DB,FINEST;NBA,FINE;SYSTEM,FINE;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,FINER;WAVE,FINEST;WORKFLOW,FINER
11:21:47.0 (436442)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|005220000019GWV|mangesh.khapre@ust-global.com.carynhealthdev|(GMT-07:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Los_Angeles)|GMT-07:00
11:21:47.0 (7021361)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00D220000004e5N||301220000009nOt
11:21:47.0 (7279293)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_END|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|2-Factor Authentication
11:21:47.10 (10753114)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|005220000019GWV|mangesh.khapre@ust-global.com.carynhealthdev|(GMT-07:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Los_Angeles)|GMT-07:00
11:21:47.10 (10787884)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|2-Factor Authentication
11:21:47.10 (10824074)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_LIMIT_USAGE|SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
11:21:47.10 (10850968)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_LIMIT_USAGE|SOQL query rows: 0 out of 50000
11:21:47.10 (10859282)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_LIMIT_USAGE|SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
11:21:47.10 (10868064)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_LIMIT_USAGE|DML statements: 0 out of 150
11:21:47.10 (10878409)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_LIMIT_USAGE|DML rows: 0 out of 10000
11:21:47.10 (10886508)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_LIMIT_USAGE|CPU time in ms: 0 out of 15000
11:21:47.10 (10898492)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_LIMIT_USAGE|Heap size in bytes: 0 out of 6000000
11:21:47.10 (10905281)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_LIMIT_USAGE|Callouts: 0 out of 100
11:21:47.10 (10913124)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_LIMIT_USAGE|Email invocations: 0 out of 10
11:21:47.10 (10919843)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_LIMIT_USAGE|Future calls: 0 out of 50
11:21:47.10 (10927072)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_LIMIT_USAGE|Jobs in queue: 0 out of 50
11:21:47.10 (10933809)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_LIMIT_USAGE|Push notifications: 0 out of 10
11:21:47.10 (11094827)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|FlowRecordCreate|Create_Verification_Record
11:21:47.10 (36875977)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|FIELDSETS_DESCRIBES|1|100
11:21:47.10 (37495194)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|FIELDSETS_DESCRIBES|2|100
11:21:47.10 (37653981)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_DETAIL|FlowRecordCreate|Create_Verification_Record|1
11:21:47.10 (37669265)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|DML|1|150
11:21:47.10 (37682905)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|DML_ROWS|1|10000
11:21:47.10 (94624378)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|Create_Verification_Record|true
11:21:47.10 (94643693)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|RecordID|a04220000015aRxAAI
11:21:47.10 (94855533)|FLOW_ELEMENT_LIMIT_USAGE|1 DML statements, total 1 out of 150
11:21:47.10 (94872766)|FLOW_ELEMENT_LIMIT_USAGE|1 DML rows, total 1 out of 10000
11:21:47.10 (94884809)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|FlowRecordCreate|Create_Verification_Record
11:21:47.10 (94907945)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|FlowRecordLookup|Get_Email_Address
11:21:47.10 (195553279)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|FIELDSETS_DESCRIBES|3|100
11:21:47.10 (196237289)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|FIELDSETS_DESCRIBES|4|100
11:21:47.10 (222226898)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|SOQL_ROWS|1|50000
11:21:47.10 (222264460)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|SOQL|1|100
11:21:47.10 (222272244)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|AGGS|1|300
11:21:47.10 (222729617)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|Get_Email_Address|true
11:21:47.10 (222738998)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|EmailAddress|mangesh.khapre@ust-global.com
11:21:47.10 (222762272)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_DETAIL|FlowRecordLookup|Get_Email_Address|1
11:21:47.10 (222857742)|FLOW_ELEMENT_LIMIT_USAGE|1 SOQL queries, total 1 out of 100
11:21:47.10 (222871962)|FLOW_ELEMENT_LIMIT_USAGE|1 SOQL query rows, total 1 out of 50000
11:21:47.10 (222884471)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|FlowRecordLookup|Get_Email_Address
11:21:47.10 (222907196)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|FlowRecordLookup|Get_Verification_Code
11:21:47.10 (228121509)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|FIELDSETS_DESCRIBES|5|100
11:21:47.10 (228531938)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|FIELDSETS_DESCRIBES|6|100
11:21:47.10 (248575453)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|SOQL_ROWS|2|50000
11:21:47.10 (248599370)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|SOQL|2|100
11:21:47.10 (248606568)|LIMIT_USAGE|[EXTERNAL]|AGGS|2|300
11:21:47.10 (248760620)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|VerifcationCode|338284
11:21:47.10 (248768198)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|Get_Verification_Code|true
11:21:47.10 (248785966)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_DETAIL|FlowRecordLookup|Get_Verification_Code|1
11:21:47.10 (248864599)|FLOW_ELEMENT_LIMIT_USAGE|1 SOQL queries, total 2 out of 100
11:21:47.10 (248875057)|FLOW_ELEMENT_LIMIT_USAGE|1 SOQL query rows, total 2 out of 50000
11:21:47.10 (248887243)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|FlowRecordLookup|Get_Verification_Code
11:21:47.10 (248909803)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|FlowActionCall|Send_Email_Verification_Code
11:21:47.10 (254511642)|WF_EMAIL_SENT|Reference:emailSimple|Recipients:mangesh.khapre@ust-global.com |CcEmails:
11:21:47.10 (254881093)|FLOW_ACTIONCALL_DETAIL|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|Send_Email_Verification_Code|Send Email|emailSimple|true|
11:21:47.10 (254900710)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|Send_Email_Verification_Code|true
11:21:47.10 (254958134)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|FlowActionCall|Send_Email_Verification_Code
11:21:47.10 (323700491)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_END|451708570adb72f82d7b3d6a362c16b7611327e-1b08|2-Factor Authentication
11:21:47.326 (326380946)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|005220000019GWV|mangesh.khapre@ust-global.com.carynhealthdev|(GMT-07:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Los_Angeles)|GMT-07:00
11:21:47.346 (346831494)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_BEGIN
11:21:47.346 (346831494)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for SOQL operations
11:21:47.346 (346831494)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for SOSL operations
11:21:47.346 (346831494)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for DML operations
11:21:47.346 (346831494)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for method invocations
11:21:47.346 (346831494)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_END

Comment: can post component Code, your component must need to implement the `lightning:availableForFlowScreens`

Comment: It's already there.. otherwise I wouldn't be able to view it in flow.. Anyways added code.

Comment: can you take out `navigate.fire();`  line and try again. you don't need to fire

Comment: got the issue.. yeah navigate.fire() is not required.. I am passing cmp to the controller function and doing component.get in the body... that is the problem

Comment: can you add working code, so it'll help for others